# Sharing Forms authentication between newer MVC and older VB.Net projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, authentication

My company has an old 3.5 webforms VB.Net application that is needs to share authentication with a newer framework 4.5.1 MVC5 C#.Net application.

The newer application is based on a popular default MVC5 template, using Forms authentication, storing authentication as tokens, as I understand it.

The old VB application has no security currently, but needs to share in the new application's authentication. I have found numerous posts and articles that touch on this, but not to the extent that I can get a working example.

I have configured the web.config files for both sites to have identical (except defaultUrl) authentication and machinekey segments; see snip below for the old VB.Net application:

```html
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="../MVCApp/Account/Login"
         defaultUrl="Home.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"
         enableCrossAppRedirects ="true" domain="localhost" requireSSL="false"/>
    </authentication>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="A225194E99BCCB0F6B92BC9D82F12C2907BD07CF069BC8B4"
                validationKey="6FA5B7DB89076816248243B8FD7336CCA360DAF8"
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

I have installed both sites locally under IIS as "localhost/VBApp" and "localhost/MVCApp". Where I'm stuck is, what do I do now?

I can log in to the MVCapp and click a link to get to VBApp, which loads fine, but does not seem to receive the authentication ticket. If I put on authorization segment in VBApp's web.config with deny users=?, I can't get in. Am I looking to read the authentication ticket from the MVCApp, and manually set IsAuthenticated to true? I guess what I'm looking for is a good tutorial that might show a bit more depth on sharing this type of authentication.

Thank you for your time.